# Removing Session Data not working

Tags: php, arrays, session, yii

I am storing some data in `session` upon some `action`. When the `user` clicks the link it creates an `array` of `arrays`. Now upon certain action I am trying to delete specific `array`. It gets deleted and upon refreshing the page it appears again.

This is how I am creating the session array:

```
    $arr = array('item_id' => $item->id, 'title' => $item->title, 'price' => $item->price, 'user_id' => $item->user_id, 'image_url' => $photo->image_url, 'type' => $item->type);
$_SESSION['cart'][$item->id] = $arr;
```

Array is like this:

```
Array
(
    [103] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 104
            [title] => Roll Paratha
            [price] => 25
            [user_id] => 10
            [image_url] => 3494655857Food-HD-Wallpaper-Download.jpg
            [type] => Photo
        )

    [104] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 106
            [title] => Qeema Mattar
            [price] => 25
            [user_id] => 92
            [image_url] => 384899841160323-pakistan-pakistani-cultural-foods.jpg
            [type] => Photo
        )

)
```

And I am doing this to remove array from session:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart'][103]);
```

This removes it and upon refreshing, it appears again, any idea?

Comment: show your creating functions

Comment: @NabinKunwar I have eddited the question, please take a look

Comment: When you reload the page, your array is getting written back to session I guess.

Comment: Nothing on that. so on page reload it's recreating that data. may be

Comment: You `unset($_SESSION['cart'][103]);` inside a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unsetting the wrong variable.

If you create your session value like this:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $arr;
```

then PHP will place $arr into `$_SESSION['cart'][0]` because it assigns an auto-incrementing key.

So your session array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [103] => item
                    [104] => item
                )

        )

)
```

If you unset `$_SESSION['cart'][0][103]` you will achieve the effect you want.

My advice would be to assign this differently though, so change your assignment to be like this:

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = $arr
```

Comment: I have updated my question, I am actually doing $_SESSION['cart'][$item->id] = $arr; . So, it makes it like this $_SESSION['cart'][103] = $arr;, so now how would i achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: Include the output of print_r($_SESSION) in your question.  I notice that you're unsetting 103 but the item_id in the array is 104.

Comment: It actually worked, the problem was, i was actually doing `$_SESSION['cart'][] = $arr;` , instead of `$_SESSION['cart'][$item->id] = $arr;`. Thanks for help!